# Mailcow - emails stuck in sending queue for localhost domain

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, smtp, sendmail

I have mailcow installed using docker and runs very well in sending and receiving mails using  the defined domain. I have no customization implemented or configured. BUT..

I have the following issue:
From the Docker host system there were some system emails sent to root@localhost. This emails are stuck

```
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "rcpt": "root@localhost",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "from": "",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "user": "unknown",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "rl_info": "bounce_to(RL7o39sx5xp11kahu376cub)",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "rl_name": "bounce_to",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "rl_hash": "RL7o39sx5xp11kahu376cub",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "qid": "AEC2F16A1EEE",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "ip": "172.22.1.1",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "message_id": "202204020441.2324f1Gx2828316@localhost",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "header_subject": "Warning: could not send message for past 4 hours",
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   |   "header_from": "Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON@localhost>"
mailcowdockerized-watchdog-mailcow-1   | }
```

So question(s):

1. How can I remove them from the queue ?
2. Optional - If any of you know, how can I map the rcpt: root@localhost to a specific real email address?
   I thank you for any hints or even links where I can find out more.

Comment: Is there anything in the Mailcow interface to process the queue? Normally you could just run `sendmail -q`. Usually the `root` user has an alias configured in `/etc/aliases` and after updating that file run `newaliases`. However, I'm not sure how Mailcow manages this or perhaps you create an alias in their interface?

Comment: So for process queue, I found the <mailcow host>/debug and there in Logs > RateLimits and I can delete the hash for which a message is queuing. But I still can't get the @localhost to have it delivered.. will continue investigating.

PS: I did the aliases but on the Docker host machine, will try to do on the postfix container maybe.

Comment: So in postfix I have the following log lines>

`04/06/2022, 06:45:07 PM info 47CCD16A0BC0: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from unknown[172.22.1.1]: 4.7.1 Ratelimit "bounce_to_ip" exceeded; from=<> to=<root@localhost> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
04/06/2022, 06:45:07 PM info 47CCD16A0BC0: message-id=<202204042101.234L11sk1602504@localhost>
04/06/2022, 06:45:07 PM info 47CCD16A0BC0: client=unknown[172.22.1.1]`

Comment: Basically i would suggest that you use the official mailcow support on telegram by using https://t.me/mailcow